# Null or empty check for a string variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null, null-check

```
if((isnull(@value,''))='')
```

I want to know whether the above piece of code works in checking if the variable is null or empty.

Comment: That would depend on the type of `@value`.

Comment: @Pete: Not in SQL Server.

Comment: its a INT type. i want to consider 0 as valid.. want to eliminate only NULL and '' values

Comment: @Bharath '' is not a valid value for an `INT`, so no need to check for that case if the type is really `INT`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, that code does exactly that.

You can also use:

```
if (@value is null or @value = '')
```

#### Edit:

With the added information that `@value` is an `int` value, you need instead:

```
if (@value is null)
```

An `int` value can never contain the value `''`.

Comment: Also important to know that you should stick to using "is null " or "is not null" when dealing with comparisons that may or not be null.

Comment: what about if (LEN(@value) is null) when @value is string?

Comment: @rivaldid: That's the same thing as checking if the value is null. The length of a string is only null when the string is null. If the string has a zero length, the `len` function returns zero, not null.

Answer (score 11):

Use This way is Better

```
if LEN(ISNULL(@Value,''))=0
```

This check the field is `empty` or `NULL`

Comment: I like this but modified it:
    
    if ''=ISNULL(@Value,'')

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you could also use `COALESCE(@value,'')=''` which is based on the ANSI SQL standard:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(@value,'')='' 
    THEN 'Yes, it is null or empty' ELSE 'No, not null or empty' 
    END AS IsNullOrEmpty
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12627/0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works. Check the below example. Assuming @value is not `int`

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT NULL AS test
    UNION
    SELECT '' AS test
    UNION
    SELECT '123' AS test
)

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN isnull(test,'')='' THEN 'empty' ELSE test END AS IS_EMPTY 
FROM CTE
```

Result :

```
IS_EMPTY
--------
empty
empty
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ISNULL(IIF (ColunmValue!='',ColunmValue, 'no units exists') , 'no units exists') AS 'ColunmValueName'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    IF (LEN(@value) > 0) PRINT 'Variable is not null and not empty'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<column_name> is null
```

in the `where` clause.

Comment: Your answer could be made more to the person asking the question if you add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.....

```
DECLARE @value Varchar(100)=NULL
IF(@value = '' OR @value IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    select 1
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    select 0
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sexo as char(1)

select @sexo='F'

select * from pessoa

where isnull(Sexo,0) =isnull(@Sexo,0)
```